# how to pcb mount a mil dtl 38999 connector

Tags: pcb, connector

Im on this website

http://www.peigenesis.com/en/amphenol-connectors/amphenol-tv-ctv-tri-start-mil-dtl-38999-series-iii.html#create-pn-military

This are military spec connectors. I'm currently using the D38999/20
Wall Mount Receptacle on a metal box, on the other side of the plug within the box all wires are placed in a wire to board connector which is the soldered on a PCB.

I wish to solder the connector directly to the PCB without the need of the second connector, making the PCB parallel to the box wall. Is this possible? with pins?

For example plug all pins in the connector and use them as through hole pins. soldering them to the PCB.

Thanks!

Comment: Contact technical support and ask for a pcb mount equivalent.  Or, make a footprint that matches the back of the connector, crimp short, uninsulated solid core wires into the connector then solder to PCB.  Given that thing is intended for high reliability situations, you might want to contact the supplier/manufacturer before you start trying to make it fit where it wasn't intended, though.

Comment: We use them here but ran into huge lead times so good luck finding any in stock. We ended up doing exactly as JRE suggested crimping the pins to solid wire and then soldering to the PCB. It was the only way we could continue to ship product.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the wrong part. Try [here](http://www.amphenol-aerospace.com/pdf/catalogs/PCB_Selection_Guide.pdf) for 38999 series connectors with pcb pins.

Note - It only required a Google of "Amphenol 38999 pcb mount"